# How to change pages through Navigator.pages API in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to pass a new pages stack trough ChangeNotifyer. Documentation says that *'A change in Navigator.pages will trigger an update to the stack of Routes.'*. But nothing happens in my case, though my pages list is updating. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong please.

https://gist.github.com/vadimtsabutashvili/a5ebfaa4f28effe6f360359a8bec8480

Comment: @pskink I tried your line, it started to chrash the App with _!keyReservation.contains(key) assert fails_ error. I don't know if it's good or bad thing. 
Also I added print to _ontap_ method to see the difference between _navState.pages_ and _List.of(navState.pages)_ and the list came out exactly the same.

Comment: @pskink It worked! I rewrote everything from the scratch, made it a bit simplier and used List.of() and it worked. Thanks!